# Like button not publish on my wall

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I just add like button on my website but when I click to publish like that :
[image: Publish box]
the post does not appear on my Wall. Why ?
Here the html code of my button :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="###URL | Permalink###" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I think you missed out `data-href="http://www.example.com"`

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/CqNMG/

Comment: I think it takes the current URL for this parameter, no ?

Comment: I just tried your code, but it doesn't work for me... `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://centpourcent-vosges.fr/sport/sports-hiver/les-jeunes-tout-schuss-a-ventron-a625.html" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
                        </li>`

Comment: Thanks,
In fact, I have an error in Facebook Meta on my page, I can debug it thanks to facebook debugger http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug